# Extracting NDVI value using zonal statistic

Tags: qgis

I am just new to GIS. I have a shapefile of a city and a file with 300 locations (latitude and longitude) from different parts of this city. I get the NDVI map by using Google Earth Engine and adding it to QGIS. now I want to extract the value of NVDI for all locations as a table. I know I should use Zonal statistics in QGIS but when I want to calculate NDVI I don't have the band I need. I mean it doesn't appear in QGIS. I can't find where is my problem.

My code so far is built like this:

```
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/000000/assets/name of city");

Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'geodesic polygon');

var imagecol = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
  .filterDate('2014-05-01', '2016-07-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(5, 7, 'month'))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false)

var getNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var withNDVI = imagecol.map(getNDVI);

var greenest = withNDVI.qualityMosaic('NDVI');
var NDVI = greenest.select('NDVI');

var NDVI = NDVI.clipToCollection(geometry)

var visParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(NDVI, visParams, 'NDVI');
 Export.image.toDrive({
  image: NDVI,
  description: 'NDVI_name_of_city_2004',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels:1e13, 
  region: geometry
});
```

Comment: If you want to calculate zone statistics in GEE you should use reduceRegions: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GEE the zonal statistics are calculated using the `reduceRegion` function. Assuming your polygons for calculating zonal statistics are stored in the FeatureCollection `geometry`, you can use the following:

```
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection('projects/000000/assets/name of city');

Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(geometry, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'geodesic polygon');

var imagecol = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR")
  .filterDate('2014-05-01', '2016-07-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(5, 7, 'month'))
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .sort('CLOUD_COVER', false)

var getNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var withNDVI = imagecol.map(getNDVI);

var greenest = withNDVI.qualityMosaic('NDVI');
var NDVI = greenest.select('NDVI');

var NDVI = NDVI.clipToCollection(geometry);

var zonalNDVI = NDVI.reduceRegions({
  collection: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 30,
  crs: 'EPSG:3310',
});

print(zonalNDVI);
```

As you can see the FeatureCollection `zonalNDVI` contains a property called `mean` with the mean value of the NDVI pixels inside each polygon. Finally you can export `zonalNDVI` to your Google Drive as a GeoJSON file using:

```
Export.table.toDrive({collection: zonalNDVI, fileFormat: 'GeoJSON'});
```

Comment: many thanks for your great help. I used this code and it worked well. I have another question. I have a Polygon of a city and I have 317 unique geocode, it is possible to save the geocode and Polygon as a single layer and then import it as an asset and at last run the code you provided? because I just want the value of the 317 geocode. @sermomon

Comment: @fary the geocodes are points? Do yo want obtain the mean NDVI un your period 2014-2016 at each point right?

Comment: yes exactly. I want to obtain the value of the NDVI at each location at the start time of the study (which is 2014) and then I want to have the mean NDVI for the period 2014-2016 at each point. I should have two values for the NDVI. I have a CSV file for geocode. @sermomon

Comment: @fary You should add another question with this doubt!